# 100% nested div height within table row

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the inner divs within the bottom row of this table fill the bottom half of the table in height. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/6QGDn/1/

This is what I see in Firefox 28.0

[image: Firefox screenshot]

**EDIT:** This was fixed by using the `.relative` class on the td in the bottom row. Problem solved, thanks for your help.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Top Row 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Top Row 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Top Row 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Top Row 4
    </td>
    <td>
      Top Row 5
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="no-border relative" colspan="5">
      <div class="left-half">
        <div class="div-td">
          Bottom Row 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-half">
        <div class="div-td">
          Bottom Row 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
      width: 400px;
      height: 240px;
}
table, td, tr, .div-td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
}
.no-border {
      border: none;
}
.relative {
      position: relative;
      height: 50%;
}
.left-half {
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
}
.right-half {
     float: right;
     height: 100%;
     width: 50%;
}
.div-td {
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use table tags there too? You may use a two column table footer `<tfoot></tr><td>left</td><td>right</td></tr></tfoot>` and assign 50% width each via CSS.

Comment: @feeela looks like a good idea, I'll try it out